# Presario v2136 AP: Which Ubuntu OS Version?

Tags: version

I have a Compaq Presario V2136AP (processor: 1.6GHz, system memory: 224 MB). I want to install Ubuntu. I am unsure of the OS version to opt for.

Please help.

Thanks,
Astik

Comment: Add more RAM (memory) if you can.

Comment: If nothing works with this RAM, I intend to add RAM. However, this being my third system (second laptop), I do not have a timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the lightest version, [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

12.04 because there is no big difference in performance between 10.04 and recent versions but you'll getting a lot of great things with latest software and kernel version.

At first I also suggested [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) but then I saw [this comparison](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lubuntu_vs_Xubuntu), according to it Lubuntu will work better on laptop with such amount of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the information. How would Ubuntu 11.10 perform?

Comment: Pretty much the same, if you are talking about Lubuntu 11.10, [here](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1204-now-available) you can find improvments over 11.10. If you're talking about actual Ubuntu - it's not the best choice because lack of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Well the latest version (12.04 Desktop) requires 384 MB of memory so I wouldn't advice you in using that, but you can use (12.04 Server) it requires only 128 MB of memory so go for it.

Alternatively if you don't want to use the Ubuntu then Xubuntu is always there for an option. It will run smooth without any laggings for a proper Linux experience :)

Comment: Thanks for the information. How would Ubuntu 11.10 perform?

Comment: Unfortunately it too requires 384 MB of memory

Read here >> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#System_Requirements